# Need help with this phrase

Tags: translation

I am doing research on martial arts, about a technique called Guī Bèi Gōng (龟背功), "Turtle back Work". There are few english descriptions of the exercises in this technique, so I have tried using google translates to decipher Chinese language sites about it. This phrase 扣畢復摩 Kòu bì fù mó, comes out as "deduction is complete". Breaking it down by word, it is closer to "Press completely again Rub". Any help in refining this translation would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 龜背功為硬功外壯，屬陽剛之勁。此功**專練背部，使之堅實**，與腹部之布袋功、鐵牛功等法，效用相同，用以禦敵，非用以制敵也。

practising this art, would strengthen one’s back, make it harder, like a carapace / tortoise shell

> 扣畢復摩

i would shortcut it to “**massage [one’s back] after knocking**”

in details, “扣” is

> 以拇指，扣住中、食二指之第一節，使其第二節骨突出，即用突出之處，向腰部軟當上環扣之

use one thumb hold the first joint of index finger & middle finger, let the second knuckles protruding, use these knuckles to “knock” one’s back

畢: finished (完畢)

復: again, and then

摩: massage (按摩)

> 以兩手緊按後腰，先向內揉摩三十六次，復向外揉摩三十六次，如此為一轉

seriously, do you believe it?

[龜背功:此功專練背部，使之堅實(圖文)](https://kknews.cc/zh-mo/health/2k26pkg.amp)

be cautious

Comment: Thank you. This was exceedingly helpful, and has definitely pointed me in the right direction. I believe I can now accurately translate the rest of it.

Comment: @Walter, you’re welcome  ask again if you need help ‍☠️

Comment: In terms of 扣 Kòu being "knock" does that mean punch or rub into, like rubbing in a massage?

Comment: @Walter,  like knocking on a door, using the second knuckles of index finger & middle finger. “knock, knock” “who’s there” 

Comment: Again, totally helpful. I wish I could share my final translation and re-write with you. Thank you for your help